# Get date stamp from jsp and set as attribute in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

In my servlet, I want to sort a query from my database by its date stamp. I want users to be able to click on the date stamp in a jsp page,

```
<td><a href="/edit"><c:out value= "${log.properties.date}" /></td>
```

which directs them to the `/retrieve` servlet. Is there a way that I can have the servlet store the `"${log.properties.date}"` date stamp? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your anchor to

```
<a href="/edit?timestamp=<c:out value="${log.properties.date}" />"> ... </a>
```

Now the timestamp will be available as a String request parameter. From your servlet:

```
String strTimestamp = request.getParameter("timestamp");
```

Parse it accordingly.

Comment: of course you can use simple form in the <a> tag. Withdrawal from cout tag in href. like following: `<a href="/edit?timestamp=${log.properties.date}"`>

Comment: As @RasoulTaheri said, you can do that too. Just don't forget the parameter key.